# How to call functions from a .eex file

Tags: tags, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to learn Phoenix, and ran into a question. In Rails I could say

```
<%= Rails.version %>
```

to get the current rails version displayed in a .erb file. I asked about how to do this in Phoenix, and got the answer

```
:application.get_key(:phoenix, :vsn)
```

Unfortunately, this highlights my ignorance as I try to ramp up with Phoenix. When I put

```
<%= :application.get_key(:phoenix, :vsn) %>
```

in my .eex file, I get

```
no function clause matching in Phoenix.HTML.Safe.Tuple.to_iodata/1
```

Please point me to any docs that help me to learn what to try next. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `:application.get_env` call returns a tuple in the format:

```
{:ok, '1.0.0'}
```

Phoenix.HTML.Safe does not have a function to decode a tuple in this format ([source](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_html/blob/267ba86cdae660115c560a95829119db66b91ff4/lib/phoenix_html/safe.ex#L71)).
You will need to extract the version from the call:

```
<%= :application.get_key(:phoenix, :vsn) |> elem(1) %>
```

However a better way would be to use a helper function:

```
defmodule VersionHelper do
  def version do
    case :application.get_key(:phoenix, :vsn) do
      {:ok, vsn} -> vsn
      _          -> #raise or return null or something else
    end
  end
end
```

This can then be called in your view with `VersionHelper.version` - this means that your fetching of the version is not tied to the key that phoenix uses in the view.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help.